# Get elements from a recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Recently I implemented Heap's algorithm in order to generate all permutations of a list of numbers. However, in all examples I have seen so far the array is printed in the base case and not returned. I want to store all the elements returned by this method (heapsAlgorithm) into a list (i.e., List). 
How do I do that?

```
public void heapsAlgorithm(int size, int[] array) {
    if (size == 1){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // here I want to add this array to a list
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            heapsAlgorithm(size - 1, array);
            if(size%2==0 ){
                swap(array[i], array[size-1]);
            } else {
                swap(array[0], array[size-1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a `List` and append a copy of your array to that where you now print it.

```
public void heapsAlgorithm(int size, int[] array, List<int[]> result) {
    if (size == 1){
        result.add(array.clone());
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); // here I want to add this array to a list
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            heapsAlgorithm(size - 1, array, result);
            if(size%2==0 ){
                swap(array[i], array[size-1]);
            } else {
                swap(array[0], array[size-1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers! I did something similar, but without .clone() when I added to the list.